# How to get value from a cookie using postman pre-requests script?

Tags: javascript, cookies, postman

I have a cookie that was stored by a login request. I'm making a new request to the same domain and different endpoint and trying to access that cookie through pre-request script using `pm.cookies.get('Auth')` but it always returns `null`. How can I get that cookie?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it in the Tests tab?

Comment: Yes, it works but I need it on the pre-request tab

Comment: Why do you need it there, if the cookie is coming from the request, you would need to get it after the request has run.

Comment: You could also try with this https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmcookiesjar